# mongoskin causing node to crash - "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I'm trying to learn to use Node.js, aswell as Express.js, Angular.js and MongoDB by following a [tutorial](https://blog.udemy.com/node-js-tutorial/), since this would be my first time dabbling with these technologies.

Everything worked perfectly up until the point where I had to test the JSON Objects. (On the end of Step 2: Creating an API with Express).
For some reason, the browser won't connect at all, and on my command line, I get an error that says nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting. Could that be related?

I'm sorry for how ambiguous the question is, but I'll gladly answer any questions needed in order to get this to work.

Massive thanks in advance

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with mongoskin module and not your code. Check the versions of your dependencies by running `npm version`. And try uninstalling and reinstalling mongoskin with

```
npm uninstall mongoskin --save
npm install mongoskin@1.3.20 --save
```

per suggestions [here](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/issues/153).

Comment: I got an error which I assume is related to Monk, which I couldn't get to work properly either. 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1864688/err2.png

I'm sorry, but all this is really overwhelming for the first time.

Comment: Hey! So as it turns out, you ended up teaching me that I can specify which versions to install. To work around that error, I ran "npm install mongodb@1.4", and got everything else to work after that.

I've already flagged your answer as correct, and would like to thank you helping me get through this!

Comment: Oh good, I deleted my earlier comment because at a second glance I noticed that you do have mongodb, just an older version! Good luck!